# How to dynamically load a page content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop home page which is mobile friendly and can load the content dynamically so that home page load is faster. For e.g: Home page should load 2 pages initially , then as the user scrolls, the home page should load more contents and so on. Second problem is that existing home page somehow has a right scroll on mobile. Need to remove the right scroll on mobile.  homepage address is https://11mantras.com

Comment: Load other pages on scroll bases.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, any thoughts on what would be the javascript code for dynamic page loading on scroll event

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should read about [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to understand the basic concepts.
It's the basic technology that lets you load content of your page dynamically.

Be aware that there are a lot of frameworks and libraries that help you load content more comfortable than building your own AJAX requests, but that depends on what technology you're using to build your Homepage.

Comment: Thanks Jay, aware of Ajax. Page is in php, what I need is a code snippet on scroll event to fetch the contents. It would be reading similar to yahoo mail, similar to lazy loading of html on scroll. One of the examples is tribunnews . if you check this portal, the onload time of the page for the first time is very less, now as the user keeps on scrolling, more and more html content is getting loaded.

Comment: Well there is a ton of tutorials for this online, e.g. look at https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/infinite-scroll-pagination-with-php-and-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

the horizontal scroll is there because of your image and ad-script if you want to do some action in mobile on right of left swipe you have to use jquery for that there is an event for this for E.g. look this function

```
 $("p").on("swiperight",function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```